# Could I subset a data.table by row using logical subsetting and keying?

Tags: r, data.table, key

I would be interested if it is possible to combine logical rowsettings and keying. I show through my code what I mean by that:

```
dt <-  data.table(var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 2), 
                  var2 = seq(1, 20, 2), 
                  var3 = ceiling(rnorm(10, 3, 2)))

#subsetting by logical expression
dt[var1 == "A" & var2 == 1] # ok
dt[var1 == "A" & var2 == c(1, 3)] # not working due to multiple criteria in var2, keying is necessary

#subsetting by using keys
setkey(dt, var2)
dt[.(c(1, 3))] # ok
dt[.(c(1, 3) & var1 == "A")] # not working, could I make it work?

setkey(dt, var1, var2)
dt[.("A", c(1, 3))] #ok
```

So clearly I could not manage to combine logical rowsetting and keys but I do not know if my syntax is incorrect or really you cannot combine these two ways to subset? I understand that if I turn all interested columns to keys I can solve the problem.

Comment: maybe `dt[var1 == "A" & var2 %in% c(1, 3)]` for the first, and `dt[.(c(1, 3))][var1 == "A"]` for the second?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do it by specifying the `on` argument:

```
dt[.(var1 = "A", var2 = c(1,3)), on = .(var1, var2), nomatch = 0]
```

Or with *chaining* as chinsoon12 suggests:

```
dt[.(c(1, 3))][var1 == "A"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` table way is `dt[i,j,by]`, so a column subset is done using `j`.

```
# To get a logical use 
dt[,var1 == "A" & (var2 ==c(1,11))]
#TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# to return the actual values 
dt[dt[,var1 == "A" & (var2 ==c(1,11))]]

#   var1 var2 var3
# 1:    A    1    4
# 2:    A   11    1
```

Comment: I understand that the solution works what you showed but I would like to focus on row based subsetting because I would like to reserve the j index for eg. selecting columns to return...etc

Comment: Didn't get you, the first returns a logical, and the second `dt` is row based selection using logical.

Comment: I see. Thank you. That's great.